# Access GCP VM via HTTPS

Tags: django, nginx, google-cloud-platform, https

Hi everyone I have a GCP VM (Debian 10 image) running a Django REST API via Nginx and Gunicorn. Since I need to call the API via HTTPS I created a load-balancer with HTTPS frontend and HTTP connection to the VM on the backend. When I call the load balancer domain it connects via HTTPS to the VM. However, instead of the Django REST API, the standard NGINX message is displayed. If I call the IP of the VM directly, without the load balancer, it still displays the Django REST API.

How can I access the Django REST API via the load balancer through HTTPS? At the moment the NGINX standard message is displayed, which is not the intended behavior.

Also if there are other easy-to-implement ways of accessing the VM via HTTPS without the load balancer I d be interested.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the description your load balancer is converting HTTPS request to HTTP, so the VM is getting HTTP requests 80 and showing the NGINX page.
You can change the backend to use HTTPS if you must have a load-balancer, or you can remove the load balancer and open port 443 on the VM to access directly.
You can also change the API to listen on HTTP but make sure port 80 isn't publicly visible.

Comment: When I access the VM directly it displays the Django API, which is the intended behavior. When I access the VM via the load balancer it displays NGINX which is unintended. So my question is why does the VM show NGINX instead of the Django API when I open it through the load balancer? And how do I fix it so the VM shows the Django API when opened through the load balancer?

Comment: Because of the way you've set up the load balancer, seeing the NGINX page **is** intended behaviour as far as the load balancer is concerned. You've told it to take incoming **HTTPS** request and convert them to **HTTP** and the VM correctly responds by showing the NGINX page. Change your backend protocol to **HTTPS** to see your API through the load balancer.